# React Native Navigation Invariant violation

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I've been in an issue after I decide to update my RNN dependency to use the new version [v2](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/). Also using the latest **RN version 0.56**. The problem is running on IOS, it Shows the red screen with this message: "*Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or might have mixed up default and named imports*". The problem is this code works on **Android**, but . not in IOS.

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import registerScreens from './screens/index';

registerScreens();
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
    Navigation.setRoot({
        root: {
            stack: {
                options: {
                    topBar: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        component: {
                            name: 'com.passenger.MainScreen',
                            passProps: {}
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });
});
```

registerScreens(); code:

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen';
import MainScreen from './MainScreen';

export default registerScreens = () => {

    Navigation.registerComponent(`com.passenger.MainScreen`, () => MainScreen);
    Navigation.registerComponent(`com.passenger.Login`, () => LoginScreen);

}
```

Comment: Can you put the code for `registerScreens` up?

Comment: @BillPham yeah, sure.